# Sonartype Nexus - No service found for registration URL

Tags: nexus

I'm playing with Nexus setup with 2 proxy nuget feeds and 1 group feed containing the 2 proxy feeds

Works fine up until I push a package to the nuget repo.

I can see the new version partially in a Nuget feed explorer, but can only download the previous versions.

I get a lot of entries like this in the Nexus log

*UNKNOWN com.sonatype.nexus.repository.nuget.internal.v3.NugetProxySearchHandler - Unable to rewrite registration URL for: [MY PACKAGE] on repository: [PROXY FEED THAT CAN ACCESS THE PACKAGE SOURCE]. No service found for registration URL: [MY PACKAGE]

I tried to setup nexus from scratch again.

Clearing cache and rebuilding index works sometimes, but not always.

Restarting the nexus service works every time